# Azure Runbook replacement for AzCopy

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azcopy, runbook

How do I translate this AzCopy command:

`azcopy.exe sync "https://xxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/xxxxx/...."  "https://xxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/xxxxx/...." --recursive`

To an Azure Runbook command?

I played around with `Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy` but can't get it to work with 2 URI's

R. Kim

Answer (score 0):

The [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/start-azurestorageblobcopy?view=azurermps-6.13.0) Cmdlet `Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy` is part of Azure RM module as we know that `AzureRM module` is going to be retried on 29 February 2024.

- If you use the Azure RM module related cmdlets in you run book the Job will be `Suspended` automatically.
- It is recommended to use `Az` Module Cmdlets in your runbook scripts.

You can use `Start-AzStorageBlobCopy` cmdlet to copy the blobs from one storage account to another storage account.

To test this i have created a PowerShell run book with the script below (copying all the blobs from source storage account container to destination storage account container) and connected it to azure account by enabling managed identity on the automation account.

```
connect-azaccount -identity
$src=New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName <sourceStorageAccountName> -StorageAccountKey <sourcestorageaccountKey>
$dest=New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName <destinationstrgaccountName> -StorageAccountKey <destinationStorageAccountKey>
Get-AzStorageBlob -Container "<containerName>" -Context $src | Start-AzStorageBlobCopy -DestContainer "destcont" -DestContext $dest
```

Refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/start-azstorageblobcopy?view=azps-8.0.0#syntax) for more information about the Start-AzStorageBlobCopy cmdlet and the list of support parameters.

Alternatively, if you want to **AZ copy** in your run book i would suggest you to use the [Hybrid run book worker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker) which would allow you to pre-install AzCopy and then execute any runbook on that worker.

For more information on Azcopy in Automation Account you can refer to this [similar MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Sharepoint/en-US/2dbdd87a-52dc-45df-812f-6df1a1d61770/using-azcopy-from-azure-automation?forum=azureautomation#:%7E:text=If%20you%20have%20to%20install%20AzCopy%2C%20then%20your%20only%20option,any%20runbook%20on%20that%20worker.).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, The problem is dat from the source I only have the uri. I Can't get it to work with only the uri. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Kim - Currently If you want to copy blobs (using either [AZ copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy) or any cmdlets) from storage account to storage account or local storage account you must have either SAS token or Oauth Authentication or public Access key on the storage account.

Comment: I have this: "https://xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/xxxxxx/?sv=2020-04-08&st=2021-11-05T10%3A46%3A30Z&se=2099-11-06T10%3A46%3A00Z&sr=c&sp=kkkkkkkkkk&sig=yyyyyyyyyyxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%3D" 
only for the source, it works perfectly with AZCOPY, but I'm not able to translate it to work with Get-AzStorageBlob .
Any pointers?

Comment: @kim - you can use the -AbsoluteURi parameter in `start-azstorageblobcopy` cmdlet as explained here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/start-azstorageblobcopy?view=azps-8.0.0#example-5-copy-a-blob-from-a-uri

Comment: Oke, I might be doing something stupid, but I can't get it to work:
$SourceURI = "https://xxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/backups/?sv=2020-04-08&st=2021-11-05T10%3A46%3A30Z&se=2099-11-06T10%3A46%3A00Z&sr=c&sp=racwdxlt&sig=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy3D" 
$src=New-AzStorageContext $SourceURI
Get-AzStorageBlob -Container "backups" -Context $src | Start-AzStorageBlobCopy -DestContainer "destcont" -DestContext $dest

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @kim - you need to pass either SAS token, connection string, access key inorder to create the storage account context for the source and destination storage accounts and to perform copy operation from source to destination (viceversa). Refer to this [documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstoragecontext?view=azps-8.0.0) to know list of supported parameters for `New-AsStorageContext` cmdlet.